# Is there an elegant way of assigning with a default value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a more elegant way of implementing the following logic in Ruby?

```
a = nil  #=> obviously 'a' can have value but I am just setting it to nil to make this example clearer
b = a
unless b
  b = "value"
end
```

Thus, we have the value of `b` set in the end. We could have another variation of the above code, like so:

```
a = nil
b = a
b ||= "value"
```

And I can also use ternary statement to write the above as:

```
b = a ? a : "value"
```

But, if you replace variable `a` and the expression `"value"` with a long line of code, then a ternary statement starts looking ugly, too.

Can this be made more elegant and expressive somehow, or are we limited to just the above solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You almost answered your question yourself.
Namely, the two statements

```
b = a
b ||= "value"
```

can be combined into a single one:

```
b = a || "value"
```

Comment: True and I don't think we can get it any better than that while keeping it clean as well as clear but I will still wait and see if anyone can come up with something better :)

Comment: You just need to ensure that when you use this false is not a valid value for a.

Comment: It's too bad that `or` doesn't fit nicely here since it doesn't bind closely enough: `b = ( a or "value" )`

Comment: This solution is _fully_ equivalent to those samples in the question, so ensuring that `false` is not a valid value for `a` is not a defect of the answer, but the _question_!

Answer (score 3):

The `b ||= "value"` statement is much like Perl’s widely-loved `//` and `//=` operators, because in Ruby the only values that test false are `nil` and `false`. This makes its functionally identical to Perl’s `//=` operator.

How much more elegant can you get than `a ||= b`? Honestly, I don't know how much more compactly that idea can be conveyed other than making the operator shorter (and at that point you're just being silly).

Answer (score 1):

I dislike using the `||` operator for the reason Farrel pointed out in ib.’s answer. It may be right here, but I'm always frightened it will trip me up one day. So, I tend to go for the rather pedestrian:

```
b = "value"
b = a unless a == nil
```

Not pretty, I know, but safe and very explicit.

Comment: Why not to express this more clearly: `b = a.nil? ? "value" : a` or `b = if a.nil? then "value" else a end`?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misremembering, but doesn't the ternary operator in Ruby also have a gotcha?   
But I should have said "unless a.nil?", I agree.